# How do I point my Domain Name to my host on my computer (it's Xampp)

Tags: hosts

How would I point my domain name registered with GoDaddy to my host on my computer. I'm using Xampp as my server. I'm really confused, I've pointed other domain names to other hosts on the internet with nameservers, hwoever... I have no nameservers... to my knowledge. So how would I point my domain name to my host on my computer?

Comment: Do you have a static IP, or a DynDNS setup?

Comment: Your provider should offer nameserver entries that you can edit. Do they?

Comment: Are you behind a router or firewall?

Answer (score 2):

you need to go the domain manager - advanced and make an A record
pointing to your ip address